# Network doesn't work on Ubuntu

Tags: networking

I've migrated physical Ubuntu to Hyper-V 2012 with Acronis Universal Restore. It worked fine for a while till i rebooted machine. After reboot the network does come up:

[image]

But any ping or anything doesn't work. There's no firewall. I removed other networks from /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules because i tried adding multiple interfaces after reboot broken the network and it kept adding more addresses. The IP Address is from DHCP and when I was adding new LAN it was getting new addresses every time. So I removed all interfaces and after reboot eth0 showed up with old ip address again from DHCP. Still no network...

Kernel is 2.6.32-41.

Keep in mind it worked just prior reboot and that I have very little knowledge about Linux. I'm Windows guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is most unpredictable I've encountered. Changing back Hyper-V processors to 1 from 4 resolves the problem. Change it back to 2,4,6 or anything else makes the network stop working. Most likely due to no Integration Services installed yet. That I wouldn't expect...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you wanted a static Ip to start with. Also is it possible that you have an IP conflict?

You can set a static ip with this. i would recommend going back to that original ip address when it worked.

sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

```
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

sudo servce networking restart

Comment: Turns out the problem was with CPU, anything else then 1 makes the network stop. No integration services most likely is the problem here.